# hamburger drop down navigation bar is not visible when scrolling on a mobile site

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, uinavigationcontroller

I'm working with this Colorlib theme 
https://colorlib.com/wp/template/po-portfolio/comment-page-1/#comment-829144

and am wondering how to make it so the hamburger drop down navigation bar is visible when scrolling on a mobile site.

Right now i have to scroll all the way back to the top of the page to see the drop down options

Hope this make sense, thanks for any help or insight

Comment: Are you trying to have the menu fixed? meaning, it will scroll down as the user scroll downs? - if this is the case, from the demo of the theme it does seem like the menu takes up the majority of the screen's real estate on mobile, not sure how the user would see the website, if that is the case, I can think of some CSS that could help, let us know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After aplying above css it's working fine and looks as you need see the below 
screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello replace your style with below style:-

    @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
     .site-navigation {
            position: fixed;
            top: 70px;
            left: 0;
            z-index: 99;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100vh;
            background: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 12px 24px rgba(0,0,0,.09);
            visibility: hidden;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: all 0.35s;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked however, the hamburger is now stuck in the center of the mobile page.

Comment: @Simsethi see the below screenshot and if your code updated on live so please send me your link so i know well what you exactly want.

Comment: Hello @Simsethi please vote for my answer if my answer useful to you.Thanks